# ffmpeg video not playable on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp4

As a bit of a background; I wrote the famous 'Barnsley Fern' algorithm in C with SDL, since I quite liked the animation, I had it export a BMP, every x frames.

I then used `ffmpeg` to turn this into a video; using the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -r 60 -i frames/frame_%05d.bmp -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -shortest fern.mp4
```

Trying to reduce the options I also tried the:

```sh
ffmpeg -r 60 -i ./frames/frame_%05d.bmp -c:v libx264 ./fern.mp
```

Both commands works without issues, and play fine using VLC on my Linux machine; however if I transfer the video to my phone (an android) it says that the 'video can't be played'...

However if I open the video using the VLC-app on my phone it plays fine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could be the pixel format issue. try `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: Yes, that seemed to have solved the issue, thank you!